# SQL - Limiting results by day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns data for each day of the week

```
day1 result result
day2 result result
day3 result result
```

each day has hundreds of rows of results, but I only want to see the top 10 of them, but for each day.

So as an example, if I wanted just the top 3 results for each day, it would look like this.

```
day1 result result
day1 result result
day1 result result
day2 result result
day2 result result
day2 result result
day3 result result
day3 result result
day3 result result
```

basically my knowledge of the limit feature only goes as far as saying "if i do limit 10, itll just give me the first 10 rows which is all from day 1"

Im stuck at this point

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: im using postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by day order by ?) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies how you define the top 10.

Comment: It's requiring me to do a group by for the dates - is this done inside the partition?

Comment: @j_nj  works for me.  Please show the table definition, the statement you ran, and the exact error message.

Comment: @j_nj . . . There is no aggregation in this answer.  And there is no suggestion that aggregation is needed for your question.  So, `group by` should not be needed.

Comment: i think i need to contribute more information.

I am grouping results by day, by person (column 2) and by sum(column 3).

So if I have 500 people per day and each person could have multiple transactions, I want to capture all the sums for that person by day and then retrieve the top 10 for each day

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you help here?

Comment: @j_nj . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.